# Javascript parse document (page) and replace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a document and replace all instances of a NEWLINE followed by a * with some html code.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

All document maybe is impossible due browsers compatibilities. But if you want do it on some `innerHTML`, maybe can works by use `.replace()` method.

**Read more**:

- http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is the entire document held as a string? Try

```
doc.replace(/\n[\s ]*\*/g, '<The content to insert>');
```

Comment: I don't know how to make the doc a string, but I tried this and no luck: ` document.getElementById('theStuff').innerHTML.replace(/\n[\s ]*\*/g, '<The content to insert>');`